# Android Java File.delete() deletes file, then it undeletes itself

Tags: java, android

Okay, I know that this is a really weird question, but this is a very weird problem.

What I am making is a note-taking app, and basically the user can create notebooks, and then notes in each notebook. What I am having trouble with is deleting said notes.

Activity Hierarchy: Books(main activity) -> Book -> Note

Basically when you delete a note(which is done from the Note activity), the Note activity finishes, and Book calls an onResume() that looks through the notebook folder, and reloads all of the notes into a ListView. The weird thing is that when the Note activity finishes, you can not see the note in the Book activity. However if you reload it (go to Books and then back), or do anything to call the method to refresh, the note is there again with all of it's data.

Here is the code that I used to delete the note:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Are You Sure?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        File note = new File(Path);

        if(note.delete()) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(edt_note, "An Error Occurred", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();

builder.show();
```

note.delete() returns true when run.

As a sidenote, I have permission to delete on these local folders. The code to delete the notebooks runs like a charm:

```
final AppCompatActivity This = this;

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Are You Sure?");
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        File folder = new File(getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separator + Name);
        File[] notes = folder.listFiles();

        for(File note : notes) {
            note.delete();
        }

        if(folder.delete()) {
            finish();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make((ListView) This.findViewById(R.id.list_notes), "An Error Occurred", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create();

builder.show();
```

I'm really stumped on this one, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

It won't let me choose my own answer as solved, but I figured it out. Details down below.

Comment: This is slightly irrelevant to the actual question, but what version of Android are you using? Did they seriously change what used to be `Toast` to `Snackbar` or is that something else?

Comment: @Arc676 Android 4.0. I don't know what Toast is, but Snackbar is a little popup sort of thing at the very bottom of the screen.

Comment: `Toast` is exactly the same thing. Renaming such a basic class... that's got to bring compatibility issues.

Comment: @Arc676 Nevermind, just looked online, they are similar, but not the same. https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html

Comment: About the actual question: check that you `close()` all files before trying to delete. I know that it _should_ return `false` but a quick search revealed this to be one of the first possible causes.

Comment: @Arc676 Files close automatically since Java 7.

Comment: In `File note = new File(Path);` are you sure that `Path` contains what you want it to contain?

Comment: @johnHascall I'm certain, that is the same variable that is used to save the note data.

Answer (score 1):

WOW I'M DUMB! lol

What was happening is that I had a save method in onStop() that was saving the note just as the activity was ending. Whoops!